# good code, but can't compile MSB3754, MSB3755, MSB4036

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have these problems coming up, when trying to run the program in Visual Studio Community 2017 C++. I know the code is ok, but every time, this happens.

Error 1

> Error MSB3754 The reference assembly "System" is invalid. "Could not
>   load file or assembly 'System' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an incorrect format." test    C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets    220

Error 2

> Error MSB3755 Could not find reference "System". If this reference is
>   required by your code, you may get compilation
>   errors."  test    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets    220

Error 3

> Error MSB4036 The "SetEnvironmentVariable" task was not found. Check
>   the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the
>   same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and
>   implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task
>   is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the
>   *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin" directory.  test    C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets    220

Comment: Looks like this is either C++/CLI or even some other .NET language. It's definitely not C++. Anyways, for help with compiler errors, show the offending code. It's definitely not "*good code*" if it can't be compiled.

Comment: The concern is that the compilation problem come and go in a random manner.
Without modifying the code, 1/3 the compilation works and then "blocks" with the 3 copying errors above.
Therefore I change VM (fresh install VS2017) but I do the same result, (without changing anythings).

My code is based on the libntfs I upgraded:
https://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/NTFSParseLib.aspx?artkw=ntfs

It look like the problem came from VirtualStudio ( probably Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets).